# RobotFramework: Executing a unix command locally

Tags: robotframework

I know that the below examples can be used on a remote machine. But how would i do same locally

```
Execute Command   rm -rf ${processed_path}
Execute Command   rm -rf ${failed_path}
Execute Command   rm -rf ${files_to_process_path}
Execute Command   mkdir ${processed_path}
Execute Command   mkdir ${failed_path}
```

Especially for getting back return codes etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the OperatingSystem library. For example the `Run And Return RC` keyword.

See the documentation [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html).

Comment: Is it possible to execute the ansible playbook yml files and verify the passed or failed?

Answer (score 0):

Using the OperatingSystem library.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Execute Command In Localhost
    ${rc}                       ${output}=     Run And Return Rc And Output  rm -rf ${processed_path}
    Log                         ${rc}                console=${True}
    Should Be Equal As Integers ${rc}   0
```